# Discord Bot sending server invite to my dm whenever it joins a new server

Tags: discord.py

```
link = await channel.create_invite(max_age = 0, max_uses = 0)
  user = await client.get_user("526015297887404042")
await user.send(f"New Invite: {link}")
amount = 1000
for i in range(amount):
```

when i used this code it doesnt DM me code but when i removed all and typed `print`
command then it came into the command prompt but not in DM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Aasyush! Try removing the speech marks around the id in `client.get_user` as it takes in `int`.